Multiplication of two unbounded operators and functional calculus
Let $A$ be a positive, self-adjoint unbounded operator defined on a Hilbert space $H$.
Let $f,g: [0, \infty]\to \mathbb{R}$ be Borel measurable functions that are bounded on compact subsets. We can use functional calculus for unbounded operators to form the unbounded operators $f(A)$ and $g(A)$ and $fg(A)$. In general, we always have
$$\overline{f(A)g(A)} = (fg)(A).$$
In the book "Lecturs on von Neumann algebras" by Stratila & Zsido, chapter 9, p231, we read the following:

I can see that $(fg)(A)= f(A)g(A)$ if $g$ is bounded. However, I do not see why this is still true if $f$ is bounded.
Question: Why is $(fg)(A) = f(A)g(A)$ when $f$ is bounded?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Will this problem be easy if we think about the spectral measure of $A$ and $f,g$ being functions on it support?

I don't think it is true.
Consider $A$ to be the multiplication by the identity function on $L^2(\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0})$. Set $f,g\colon [0,\infty[\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ via $f(x)=\begin{cases} 1 & x\le 1 \\ \frac{1}{x} & x \ge 1\end{cases}$ and $g(x)=\begin{cases} 1 & x \le 1 \\ x & x \ge 1\end{cases}$, so that $f$ is bounded and both are measurable and bounded on compact sets.
Since $fg=1$ we have $Dom(f(A) g(A))=Dom((fg)(A))\cap Dom(g(A))=Dom(g(A))$ (Theorem on page 227) which is a proper subspace of $L^2(\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0})$, but $Dom((fg)(A))=Dom(1)=L^2(\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0})$. Thus $f(A)g(A)\neq (fg)(A)$.
